# What components are these?

Tags: transistors, components, vintage

I usually buy electronics components at an online surplus store and they usually throw in the box some more goodies to pack what you order.

I bought a multi section plastic container and it was filled with all sort of components, and this one in particular intrigues me. Here is a photo:

[image: Mystery components]

They seem to be transistors, maybe their odd shape is because they are RF or something...

Some "old school" guy that has used them?

Comment: The answer below from @jippie is likely to be correct, but are there any markings on these?

Comment: They're very colorful. Most of that type wot I've seen have been black epoxy. Are they perhaps ex-Soviet parts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Transistors in a [TO-50](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/TO50%20transistor-datasheet.html) package commonly used in RF applications. The leads can be soldered flat onto the PCB, reducing lead inductance. Can be either some type or FET or BJT.

Comment: I concur and have used devices like this in RF designs. You can still buy them from regular sources.

Comment: that was my suspect. There is no marking on them anyway...

Answer (score 4):

While they may be what Andy and jippie say, they also MAY be "MMIC"s

[Wikipedia - MMIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_microwave_integrated_circuit) aka Monolithic microwave integrated circuit.

These often have a 4 lead package with 2 opposite pins being ground, but this is not essential. And a transistor may also have 4 leads with two being ground. The image below is from the above Wikipedia page.

[image]

However, to rather meld the answers given  - a MMIC "IC" **MAY** be as simple as a single transistor with internal biasing resistors. Or a pair of transistors. Or much more.

The diagram below is a Mini-Circuits ERA series MMIC amplifier.
Diagram from Mini-Circuits AN-60-10 [BIASING MMIC AMPLIFIERS - e.g., ERA SERIES](http://s.eeweb.com/articles/2013/01/02/biasing-mmic-amplifiers-e.g.-era-series-1357190376.pdf)

[image]

Which ends up in circuit diagrams looking like this:

[image]

---

This one actually uses all 4 pins for different functions - so yours is not one of these :

[image]

BUT, some of these could be - [Table 15 from this useful page](http://homebrewcorner.blogspot.co.nz/p/rf-components-stock-as-on-oct-2012.html)

[image]

But, ALL of these with 4 leads are transistors intended for LNA use (table 1).

[image]